# I have a large query with collect_set() along with multiple joins, listing columns with aliases etc and it fails at the "AS" clause?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have this code below for my spark.sql statement all works fine until I start to try to work with the collect_set() function.

`

```
dfc = spark.sql("""
select c.Id,c.ContractNumber,c.CycleNumber,c.CycleEffectiveDate,c.CycleExpirationDate, INITCAP(c.Description) AS Description,COALESCE(GlobalAmendmentNumber, 0) AS GlobalAmendmentNumber, 
collect_set("refcat.Name") GROUP BY c.ContractNumber AS CategoryName, reftype.Name AS ContractType, refaward.name AS AwardStatus, refof.Name AS OrderFrom,refdn.NAME AS DepartmentName,
CASE
WHEN current_date() between cast(c.CycleEffectiveDate as timestamp) and cast(c.CycleExpirationDate as timestamp) THEN '1' 
WHEN current_date() < cast(c.CycleEffectiveDate as timestamp) THEN '2'
ELSE '3'
END AS ContractWeight
from contractmaster.contract c
join contractmaster.amendment am on am.Id = c.Id
join contractmaster.taxon t on t.HeaderId = c.Id
join contractmaster.referencedatum refcat on t.CategoryId = refcat.Id
join contractmaster.referencedatum reftype on c.ContractTypeId = reftype.Id
join contractmaster.header h on c.Id = h.Id
join contractmaster.referencedatum refaward on h.AwardStatusId = refaward.Id
join contractmaster.referencedatum refof on h.OrderFromId = refof.Id
join contractmaster.referencedatum refdn on h.DepartmentId = refdn.Id
WHERE am.IsExecuted = True 
AND reftype.Type = "ContractType"
AND refaward.Type = "AwardStatus"
AND refof.Type = "OrderFrom"
AND refdn.Type = "Department"
""")
```

`

The error returns saying syntax issue at the AS CategoryName right after the collect_set() statement. I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong with the groupings? If I attempt to group at the end it asks me to start grouping all other columns referenced as well. Any help would be appreciated! I'm fairly new at all of this but am sure it must be possible in a similar way to AGG functions in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Move `GROUP BY` statement to the bottom / end of sql query.

Check below `COLLECT_SET` function syntax there is no `GROUP BY` statement in it.

`collect_set(expr) [FILTER ( WHERE cond ) ]`

```
SELECT 
        c.Id,
        c.ContractNumber,
        c.CycleNumber,
        c.CycleEffectiveDate,
        c.CycleExpirationDate, 
        INITCAP(c.Description) AS Description,
        COALESCE(GlobalAmendmentNumber, 0) AS GlobalAmendmentNumber,
        COLLECT_SET(refcat.Name),
        CASE
            WHEN current_date() between cast(c.CycleEffectiveDate as timestamp) and cast(c.CycleExpirationDate as timestamp) THEN '1' 
            WHEN current_date() < cast(c.CycleEffectiveDate as timestamp) THEN '2'
            ELSE '3'
        END AS ContractWeight
FROM contractmaster.contract c
JOIN contractmaster.amendment am 
    ON am.Id = c.Id
JOIN contractmaster.taxon t 
    ON t.HeaderId = c.Id
JOIN contractmaster.referencedatum refcat 
    ON t.CategoryId = refcat.Id
JOIN contractmaster.referencedatum reftype 
    ON c.ContractTypeId = reftype.Id
JOIN contractmaster.header h 
    ON c.Id = h.Id
JOIN contractmaster.referencedatum refaward
    ON h.AwardStatusId = refaward.Id
JOIN contractmaster.referencedatum refof 
    ON h.OrderFromId = refof.Id
JOIN contractmaster.referencedatum refdn 
    ON h.DepartmentId = refdn.Id
WHERE am.IsExecuted = True 
AND reftype.Type = "ContractType"
AND refaward.Type = "AwardStatus"
AND refof.Type = "OrderFrom"
AND refdn.Type = "Department"  
GROUP BY c.ContractNumber,
         reftype.Name , 
         refaward.name, 
         refof.Name,
         refdn.NAME
```